# vim replaces lines when I move to a new line

Tags: macos, vim

I'm using Terminal.app on Mac 10.6.6 and want to upgrade vim. Should I install it in /usr/local?

I'm asking because my native vim install is messed up for some reason. Sometimes, when I open it and move up and down, the whole line changes to another line on the screen, like dancing chairs. But if I type :q it quits fine because nothing actually gets changed (cause I'm just moving the cursor around), but I can't see what I'm doing because when I move to a new line, that line gets replaced with another line about 6 lines below, but it's random.

$TERM = xterm-color

I installed Mercurial & ack via CPAN (for which I installed File:Next) yesterday, so maybe that did it. I have MacVim, but I want vim to work too cause I use it for Git, etc.

Comment: Are you using gVim (the GUI version)? If not, what terminal program are you using? What's your `TERM` environment variable set to? Does it sensibly match the terminal you're actually using?

Comment: Maybe you just have some screen corruption. Did you try to press CTRL-L in command mode?

Answer (score 2):

Put the mvim script that came with MacVim in your $PATH and use it on the terminal with the -v option or a symbolic link named vim.

Also, use TERM=dtterm for Terminal.app.  Programs will behave better.

Comment: I want to use vim, not MacVim. Read the last line in my question.

Comment: MacVim provides a cli binary.  Iirc, the mvim script just calls the MacVim provided vim binary.

Comment: Sorry, I left something out of my answer (that I did mention in #vim).

Comment: @graywh, do you have a specific reason for suggesting `dtterm`? `xterm-color` is the default because it's the most accurate and compatible description of Terminal's actual capabilities prior to Lion. As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, the default is now `xterm-256color` and Terminal is even more compatible with modern Xterm than ever before.

Answer (score 2):

Try running `vim -u "NONE"` to load your Vim without your .vimrc, this might be the culprit in this case. If everything works like it should you can try re-enabling things one by one so you can see what caused it.

If you want to update your Vim I can recommend [homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) which has a so called formula with a regularly updated Vim.